# Make JOINED query with OR in Where clause in Typeorm With Repository method

Tags: typeorm, nest

Im trying to build this query in TYPEORM using connection.getRepository method in Nestjs.

`````
                SELECT
                    "car"."RowID"
                FROM
                    "cars"."car" "car"
                    LEFT JOIN "cars"."doors" "doors" ON "car"."doorID" = "doors"."doorID"
                    LEFT JOIN "cars"."wheels" "wheels" ON "car"."wheelID" = "wheels"."wheelID"
                    LEFT JOIN "cars"."engines" "engines" ON "car"."engineID" = 
                    "engines"."engineID"
                WHERE
                        ("car"."Status" = 0 OR "car"."Status" = 2) AND
                        "car"."RetryAttempts" < 5 AND
                        ("doors"."Status" = 3 OR "doors"."Status" = 4) AND
                        ("wheels"."Status" = 3 OR "wheels"."Status" = 4) AND
                        ("engines"."Status" = 3 OR "engines"."Status" = 4)
            )``
    ````
    This is what i came up with but it doesnt work.

this.connection
            .getRepository(CarsEntity)
            .find({
                select: ["rowID"],
                join: {
                    alias: "car",
                    leftJoinAndSelect: {
                        engines: "car.engines",
                        doors: "car.doors",
                        wheels: "car.wheels",
                    },
                },
                where: {
                    retryAttempts: LessThan(5),
                    status:In([
                        0,2]
                    ),
                    engines: {
                        status: In([3,4]
                        )
                    },
                    doors: {
                        status: In([3,4]
                        )
                    },
                    wheels: {
                        status: In([3,4]
                        )
                    }
                }
            });
`````

The where clause for this query looks like this

```
WHERE
    "CarsEntity"."retryAttempts" < @0
    AND "CarsEntity"."status" IN (@1, @2)
    AND "CarsEntity"."engineID" = @3
    AND "CarsEntity"."doorID" = @4
    AND "CarsEntity"."wheelID" = @5
```

Question is from  where are are the extra fields comming from. Is it my query or should i search the entities? And what happens to my conditions for the status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to have a version equal or greater than
"typeorm": "^0.2.37",

there was a bug that is fixed in this version. Previously i was using
"typeorm": "^0.2.34